# How to use 'auth_user' table of remote database in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-authentication

I want to access 'auth_user' table from another Django project and use it in my current Django project.

I am using database routers:-

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['to.your.router.CurrentRouter']
```

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': eval(os.environ.get('DATABASE_REMOTE', str(DEFAULT_DATABASE))),
    'database_current': eval(os.environ.get('DATABASE_CURRENT', str(DEFAULT_DATABASE)))
}
```

```
class CurrentRouter:
    
    route_app_labels = {
        'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'tracking', 'data_collect'
    }

    def __str__(self):
        super().__str__()

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
     
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_current'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_current'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
      
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
       
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'database_current'
        return None
```

How can i use 'auth_user' table from DATABASE_REMOTE for logging into django admin panel and delete object from DATABASE_CURRENT. And how to set permission deleting objects in current database using User of remote database?

For logging into admin panel using remote database user I have used custom authentication.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/

```
class CustomAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
   
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
```

But when deleting an object from DATABASE_CURRENT using the DATABASE_REMOTE 'User' it throws error: userid not found. It is related to permission that User don't have for the apps in current project. How to add those permission? I also want to remove User page from current project and use User of remote project.

Is there any way in Django to use 'auth_user' table of another project?

In database routers i removed 'auth' app from route_lables so migrations won't run for 'auth_user'.